# Add elements to set iteratively

Tags: c++, algorithm

Suppose I have an array {1,2,3}, I have to add these elements to set like this

```
Pass 1: {1}, {2}, {3} (Adding sets of size 1 )
Pass 2: Pass1 + {1,2}, {1,3} , {2,3} (Combination of sets of previous pass and sets of size 2)
Pass 3: Pass2 + {1,2,3}
```

Finally my set should have `{1},{2},{3}, {2,3},{1,3},{1,2},{1,2,3}`

I tried to code this

```
void generateSets(int arr[], int size, int sum)
{
    set<set<int> > mySet;
    for(int i=0;i< size ; i++)
    {
        set< set<int> >::iterator iter;
        **for (iter = mySet.begin(); iter != mySet.end(); ++iter) 
            {**
            set<int> s(*iter);
            for(int k=0;k<size; k++)
                    {
                s.insert(arr[k]);
                }
            mySet.insert(s);
        }
    }
}
```

I am not able to generate sets like what I have mentioned. Please someone can help me on this!!

Comment: You are aware that the code (after fixing the issue) will only work for sets of size 3?

Comment: Im not sure, But im struggling in proceeding further, Im new to this kind of programming

Comment: Also, the approach you suggest will most likely lead to `O(n!)` solution, while there is O(2^n) solution

Comment: Now my first priority is to code this, then let me optimize it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to do it usually involves recursion or something similar.

The idea is to "let the recursion handle" subsets that do not include 1 element, and once you have it, you need to add the subsets that do include this element.

It should look similar to this: (this is a c++ like pseudo code, not a working code!)

```
//extend(set<set<int>>, int) is an auxilary function used by the main logic function
set<set<int>> extend(set<set<int>> original, int e) { 
   set<set<int>> result = new set<set<int>>();
   for each set<int> s in original { 
       tempSet = s.clone();  
       tempSet.add(e);
       result.add(tempSet);
   }
   return result;
}

//this is the main logic function
set<set<int> > findSets(int[] arr, int size) { 
   if (size == 0) return new set<set<int>>(new set<int>()); //return a set containing only an empty set
   set<set<int>> results = new set<set<int>>(); //result set
   results = findSets(arr,size-1); //all subsets without element arr[n-1], using recursion.
   results.union(extend(results,arr[size-1]); //add all subsets containing arr[n-1]
   return results;
}
```